# Google Search Console claims my pages are indexed and recently crawled however they do not appear when searched

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

This may be hard to diagnose
All of my pages are indexed on google search console and were all recently crawled. However, if i were to take some of my pages and search the exact content that is in the pages, they do not appear.

Where would this problem be coming from?

Comment: Do you see your content if you use site:example.com?

Answer (score 1):

As @Trebor suggested, have Google list your site pageg only, using `site:domain.com`. Otherwise the results you are getting depend on your location, user preferences, search history, etc. Try checking from a different device, and/ or use a proxy to perform the search from a different location. 
Also, check out Search console for crawlability or other issues. You may find that Google is aware about your pages and lists them all, but does not return them publicly in SERPs, because of errors (speed, crawlability, bad redirects etc..).